# How to add UIView over navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationbar

I need overlay `UINavigationBar` with `UIView` like here

[image: http://screencast.com/t/ZKXNFcAzVu]

Is there a way to do this except using custom UIView with button back as nav bar?

Comment: If you want to do this kind of stuf than better that you use custom Navigation created by UIView. Than you have complete control over it and you can give what ever look you want to give....

Answer (score 23):

You can add a subview to the base view of the Application

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:vMyCustomUIView];
```

To make sure it is only shown when your view controller is visible you could add and remove it in the `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` delegate methods. Here is an example that would show a blue box overlapping them.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.    
    vTestView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f,
                                                         10.0f,
                                                        100.0f,
                                                        100.0f)];
    vTestView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:vMyCustomUIView];
}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [vMyCustomUIView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: In swift 2...
let overlay: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height))
            overlay.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0x000000, alpha: 0.7)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.addSubview(overlay)

Answer (score 14):

Use the method :

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view
```

So in your case that will be :

```
[navigationBar addSubview:myRibbon];
[navigationBar bringSubviewToFront:myRibbon];
```

Also don't forget that with this way, your ribbon won't be showed completely except if you do this :

```
navigationBar.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

I hide NavigationBar and added UIView instead. It looks the same as Navbar.
then add more one UIView with red bookmark. Beside it give possibility to animate bookmark on touch separately.

If I added bookmark this way:
[navigationBar addSubview:myRibbon];
it was hidden on half of size

Answer (score 1):

Here's how implemented mine, hope this helps..

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let testView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    testView.backgroundColor = .black
    testView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(testView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      testView.widthAnchor
        .constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
      testView.heightAnchor
        .constraint(equalToConstant: 70),
      testView.topAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topAnchor)!),
      testView.trailingAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.trailingAnchor)!, constant: -20)
      ])
    self.customView = testView
  }
  
  // i dont need to display the overlay in every page
  // so i remove it everytime i navigate to a new page
  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.customView.removeFromSuperview()
  }
```

[image: navigation bar overlay]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Swift 3 answer

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(menuView)
```