# how to make AdMob on top?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

i have question about AdMob ,

i want to make it on top as autolayout

see the picture

[image]

```
 Banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
        Banner.adUnitID = "*********"
        Banner.rootViewController = self
        let req: GADRequest = GADRequest()
        Banner.loadRequest(req)
        Banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.bounds.height - Banner.frame.size.height, Banner.frame.size.width, Banner.frame.size.height)
        self.view.addSubview(Banner)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, Banner.frame.size.width, Banner.frame.size.height)
    self.view.addSubview(Banner)
    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(Banner)
```

Comment: thank you , i want the AD on the navigation control

Comment: i can't click [Back] Button

Comment: doesn't work bro ,

Comment: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.sendSubviewToBack(Banner)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111383/discussion-between-jayesh-miruliya-and-x-bozo).

Comment: still doesn't work , ok if i can't do it , what about if i want ADBanner under navigationBar

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
    self.view.addSubview(Banner)
```

into

```
      navigationBar.addSubview(Banner)
```

or use

```
   self.navigationController!.navigationBar.addSubview(Banner)
```

for additional information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232273/how-to-add-uiview-over-navigation-bar)

**Update**

change the frame of `Banner`, reason it occupy the full width of the navigation bar. change the `X` and `Width` and try for example

```
Banner.frame = CGRectMake(50, 0, Banner.frame.size.width - 50, Banner.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: navigationBar.addSubview(Banner) this code , doesn't work with me , i got error

Comment: can you show the error once

Comment: i just uploaded picture for the error

Comment: @X.BOZO - not like that bro, in `navigationBar.addSubview(Banner)` add `yournavigationbarname.addSubview(Banner)`

Comment: where can i find the navigationbar name ?

Comment: on your viewcontroller assign one name of your navigation bar and add subview to that , surely works

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: what the problem u faced bro and update question once

Comment: your code doesn't work, and this one works [self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(Banner)
] and but i can click on button [back]

Comment: @X.BOZO - sorry I forget this, wait I upadetd my answer

Comment: but i can't click on [Back] navigation Button

Comment: @X.BOZO - check the updated answer once

Comment: it's work thank you , can you please make it smaller

Comment: @X.BOZO - pardon bro

Comment: i want to make Ad smaller

Comment: based on your width and height it will occupy on navigation bar, what answer you need i can't understand that the reason i asked

Comment: it's ok thank you bro